# split word without split()

Tags: java, split

I managed to split a given word or sentence by a certain symbol, now I'm wondering if I can do this with multiple symbols as a string. For example if I had ("1+1=2"), and try to split it by("+=")?

I thought about declaring symbol as a String and then put the loop that I already have in another one so that ever character in word would be tested for every character in symbol, but to be honest it confuses me.

^-^ I'm thankful for any advice.

public static void splitBySymbol() {

```
    int i = 0;

    while (i < word.length()) {

      if (word.charAt(i) == symbol) {

          System.out.println( word.substring(0,i)); ;

          word = word.substring(i + 1);

          i = -1;

      }

      i++;
    }


}
```

Comment: `split` uses regex. You can split on multiple delims with `"1+1=2".split("[\\+=]");`

Comment: This is an assignment, I can't use the built-in function split ;( . but it's good to know how to do it that way, thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @Ninorin - Please give an example of your input and how you would like the output to be.

Comment: Word = "1+1=2*" , symbol = "+=*" ,                                  it should print out  1 1 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the parts, you can:

```
public static void splitBySymbol(String word, String symbols)
{
    // Check each char
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        // Get the current char and convert to string (for contains())
        String c = Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
        // If it is a delimeter, print a new line
        if (symbols.contains(c)) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        // Otherwise, print the char
        else {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```